# Why is my text not being added to the textarea after the second change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add text in the the `<textarea>` when an on change event occurs.

It works perfectly fine in the first change event. But when I delete the text inside the text area and preform another change event it does not work add the text anymore?

I am really confused on why its not working. Below is a snippet of what I am trying to accomplish.

```js
$("#test").on("change", function() {

  $("#textarea_test").text("Hello");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test" id="test">
  <option value="Test1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="Test2">Test 2</option>

</select>

<textarea name="textarea_test" id="textarea_test" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: its looks fine when `run code snippet`

Comment: @ntaloventi: It seems like you didn't read the whole question. If you perform the same steps as described by the OP, you can observe the same behavior.

Comment: @Felix King, Yups sorry... miss read

Answer (score 5):

`.text` changes the *inner content* of the textarea, which is used as **default value**. Once the value was changed by the user, changing the default value won't have any effect.

Use [**`.val`**](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to change the value, just like with any other form control element.