# InsertText function not working after keyboard use

Tags: javascript

```
function insertText(elemID, text) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
    elem.innerHTML += text;
}
```

This function works well to use buttons to add strings to a textarea in order to create a complex paragraph.

However, if the user adds/deletes/modifies that text with the keyboard, the function will no longer work until the form is refreshed, which loses the text changes.

Is there a way to modify the function to allow resuming use of the function after any keyboard edits without losing the text that has been added and modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a non-jQuery duplicate of [Why is my text not being added to the textarea after the second change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30825171/218196) .

`innerHTML` sets the **default value** of the textarea. Once the textarea was edited by the user, the **current value** is stored in the `value` property.

Use

```
elem.value += text;
```

instead.